# What is the double colon before module names in Ruby stand for?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0, ruby-2.1

I see in a lot of Ruby source code a double colon before module names, I wonder what is that all about? Here is an example from a Ruby Gem called Conductor:

https://github.com/rails/conductor/blob/master/lib/conductor/engine.rb#L7

Comment: It's short of Object::(constant)

Comment: It's a namespace resolution operator. It allows you to access items in modules, or class-level items in classes.

Comment: I don't ask about the operator itself, I ask why it is there before the module name like: **::Rails**

Comment: @Wazery - it is explained in the other question as well.

Comment: That means it is referring to the toplevel namespace.
http://pastebin.com/my4x5F9c